# Timeout exception in `if` loop while the element is visible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Trying to learn python by doing.

```
results = driver.find_element_by_class_name("n_p").text
results = int(re.sub(r'[^\d,\.]','',results))
expected_pages = int(results / 20)
print(results)
print(expected_pages)

count = 1
while count < expected_pages:
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    time.sleep(5)
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), ' Show More Results')]")))
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
    actions.click().perform()
    count = count + 1
    print(count)
print("All Done!")
```

The output I recieve when I execute it:

> 3670         #results
>
> 183    #expected_pages
>
> 2      #count

Then it gives me the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "C:\Python34\TryScroll.py", line 35, in
>
> element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*
>   [contains(text(), ' Show More Results')]")))
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 
>   80, in until
>
> raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
>
> selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

I can see the element in question i.e. it has scrolled to the end of the page where the element is located, tried to add a few seconds to see if that would fix it didn't work, the element on inspect:

`<div id="scroll3" class="fm2 p8 cur m_bt2" onclick="javascript:displayResultsLogin('scroll3')"> Show More Results </div>`

`Xpath: //*[@id="scroll3"]`

Comment: As I remember your previous issues, you have 2 buttons "Show More Results" on page, right? Or it's the same button but with changed `HTML` code after first click?

Comment: @Andersson, its the same button. Its simply retrieving more results and the `id` changes from scroll2 to scroll3 and so on. :) Here is the link: [Link](https://dir.indiamart.com/search.mp?ss=Power+Distribution+Transformers) for clarity.